# Over a 24 hour cycle does weight/resistance training increase hunger more or less than high intensity interval training (HIIT)?

Tags: hiit, resistance, hunger

I'm aware that HIIT training suppresses appetite more significantly than weight/resistance training during and just after workout.  I can't find much eveidence for its effect on appetite over a 12, 24 or 36 hour period.  Anyone know of any research that could point me in the right direction?